# looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* ro_err::StdErr::what() const’

Tags: c++

here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/bd44e03153a499a0de62), I customize exception like:

```
class StdErr : public std::exception {

public:
    str msg;

    StdErr(str msg) { this->msg = msg; };

    virtual const char *what() const override {
        return this->msg.c_str();
    };
};
```

and inherite it like:

```
class ShErr : public StdErr {

public:
    ShErr(str m) : StdErr(m) { }
};
```

and use them like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    throw ro_err::ShErr("sh err");
    return (0);
};
```

it raise `looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* ro_err::StdErr::what() const’`, I have following questions:

- what is looser?
- what is specifier?
- how to fix it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since c++11 `what()` is *noexcept*.  You have not declared it as *noexcept*.  That is what the 'looser throw specifier' is telling you. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what.

I.e. declare it like

```
virtual const char *what() const noexcept override
```

Comment: what does looser mean?

Comment: @asullaherc It is a less strict definition of the throw specification. Without it what() is allowed to throw an exception.

Comment: virtual is not needed, unless you still want to override this method

Comment: @PawełIwaneczko Omitting virtual in the inheriting class has no impact at all on the behavior of the code. I.e. It can still be overridden.