# C++: Custom formatting for exceptions uncaught by main()

Tags: c++, exception, program-entry-point

I am creating a library that contains functions that can throw exceptions. To debug programs that use my library, I would like to provide a custom format-method that will give the programmer more information about these exceptions if they are uncaught by `main()`.

Generally, my library can be called from a `main` function() written by an *end user*. The end user does not put a `try..catch` block in `main()` because the end user does not expect these exceptions (they should actually be avoided and/or caught by other, buggy libraries, between my library and `main()`, but they're not, and that's what we need to debug).

```
// The following example would actually be multiple files,
// but to keep this example simple, put it in "<filename>"
// and compile the following with "g++ <filename>".


// library file

class My_Exception
{
public:
  char const* msg;
  My_Exception(char const* msg) : msg(msg) {}
};

void Library_Function(bool rarely_true = false)
{
  if (rarely_true)
    throw My_Exception("some exceptional thing");
}
// note to discerning user: if you use the "rarely_true" feature,
// be sure to remember to catch "My_Exception"!!!!


// intermediate, buggy, library (written by someone else)

void Meta_Function()
{
  Library_Function(true); // hahahaha not my problem!
}


// main program (written by yet someone else, no "try..except"
// allowed here)

int main()
{
  Meta_Function();
}
```

When I run the above program, I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'My_Exception'
Abort (core dumped)
```

I like the way there is an error message telling me about the uncaught exception. I would like to know the best way to add a hook to `My_Exception` so that the `msg` string would also be printed in this situation.

I am willing to register callbacks with the runtime system, or add methods to `My_Exception`, but I don't want to mess with `main()` itself. (I know this problem could be solved by telling the linker to use a different entry point having a `try..catch`, and wrapping `main()` in that, but it will be hard to get the end-user to adopt something like that).

Clearly there is already some exception-checking code after `main()`, as the above message was printed. The stack trace is:

```
#0  0x0000155554c0d428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x0000155554c0f02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x000015555502e8f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000155555034a46 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000155555034a81 in std::terminate() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000155555034cb4 in __cxa_throw ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004006eb in Library_Function() ()
#7  0x00000000004006f4 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Aside: I don't at all understand why `gdb` says the program is aborting in `Library_Function`. That sounds wrong; it should at least have exited from `main()` after `main()` failed to catch the exception. Must be some language detail, like it preserves the stack until the exception is handled? In any case, I digress.

Maybe we can extend `std::terminate()` or `cxa__throw()` or some other runtime component to print `msg` in this case?

**How this question is different**

*How come I don't can't print out error from my throw exception? 2 answers* -- similar, but 1. my question involves an exception object (not a string) and therefore the point about custom formatting (in the question title) is relevant. 2. missing keyword "uncaught" from the title, so hard to find

*Custom error message of re-thrown exception not printed by what() 1 answer*
-- 1. already contains an answer to my question in their question, so cannot be the same question. Unless you consider "what tool pounds a nail" to be the same question as "why isn't my hammer working". 2. missing keyword "uncaught" from the title

*looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* ro_err::StdErr::what() const’ 1 answer*
-- 1. already contains an answer to my question in their question, so cannot be the same question. Unless you consider "what tool pounds a nail" to be the same question as "why isn't my hammer working". 2. missing keyword "uncaught" from the title

Comment: Inherit custom exceptions from `std::exception` and override the `what()` function.

Comment: @Panda Rei that looks very promising.... currently stuck on `main.cpp:15:15: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* My_Exception::what() const’`

Comment: Use `nothrow` for the declaration.

Comment: Got it working with `virtual const char *what() const noexcept override {return msg;}` and `g++ -std=c++11`. Awesome!!! Thank you. Please post as answer and I will accept.

Comment: (I got `noexcept override` from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763027/looser-throw-specifier-for-virtual-const-char-ro-errstderrwhat-const])

Comment: I am pretty sure your original question also is a duplicate, I am just too lazy to search for it right now.

Comment: BTW your aside about why GDB shows the exception coming from `Library_Function()` might make a good separate question on its own. I'd suggest removing it from here and posting it separately.

Comment: @Panda Rei  I wouldn't be surprised if there is duplicate inner content, but I couldn't find the original after searching  the obvious keywords (C++ uncaught main exception formatting). I must admit I stopped looking after the first 3 pages of results. Forgive me...

Comment: @personal_cloud It's not that hard to ping me correctly BTW: _@πάνταῥεῖ_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right, I can copy-and-paste Greek without having my keyboard set up for it. Cool! (I learn something new every day...) For `nothrow` I get: main.cpp:15:36: error: ‘nothrow’ does not name a type

Comment: @personal_cloud It's `noexcept` as you already found. I was wrong about the exact wording. Happens if it's late like that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have edited the question to explain how this one is different from the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ, you can try this

```
class myexception : public exception
{
public:    
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        char* ch = "some exceptional thing";
        return ch;
    }
};    

void Library_Function(bool rarely_true = false)
{
    if (rarely_true)
        throw myexception();
}

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        Library_Function(true);
    }
    catch (myexception& err)
    {
        std::cout << err.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accepting... the key is to not have `what() const`. Then it works and I don't have to add `noexcept override`. Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ and @seccpur.

Comment: I take it back... the above compiles, but you have to add `const noexcept override` after `what()` for it to have the correct effect. I will edit the answer if no objections.

Comment: Note that `virtual` and `override` are redundant, you can just write `override`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Edited. Thanks.